# Is there a way to get Atom to autocomplete 'html' tags when building React Apps?

Tags: reactjs, atom-editor

I'm just starting to learn React and am enjoying using it. However, it is very frustrating to me that Atom doesn't autocomplete `html` tags in `.js` files. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, install this plugin on your atom https://orktes.github.io/atom-react/#automatic-closing-tag

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I installed a community package "html-shortcuts-react", which I found quite helpful. You could go to Packages -> Settings View -> Install Packages and search for that package.